# AWS API Gateway soft quota

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

Currently, AWS API Gateway provides a mechanism for setting up Usage Plans, associations with API keys, and quota limitations for each plan or more fine-grained limits for methods. But this quota is "hard", i.e. it will restrict further API access with HTTP 429 if reached. Is there any recommended way to configure "soft" quotas – for instance, how can one just monitor events caused such limitation exceeding?

As I understand, there is nothing to with API Gateway's custom gateway responses, as they are bound to HTTP 4XX and 5XX error status codes. According to underlying idea, reaching "soft" limit is not considered as an error and API access should be still enabled.